# Angular 6: HttpClient does not work correctly on Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, microsoft-edge

In the client side (using Angular 6), I need to send a Post request to server side using HttpClient. The sample source code as below

```
    let request = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}
    this.httpClient.post("http://10.116.43.18:8002/user/login", request,  { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*'), observe: 'response' }).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
```

The sample code works correctly in Chrome, IE, however, it does not work in Edge.
I checked Network tab in Developer mode of Edge, it seems only GET request is sent (not POST request as my expectation, this is very weird). I received the below message in Edge:

> [object Object]: {error: Object, headers: Object, message: "Http
>   failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error", name:
>   "HttpErrorResponse", ok: false...}
>
> error: Object bubbles: false cancelable: false cancelBubble: false
>   currentTarget: null defaultPrevented: false eventPhase: 2 isTrusted:
>   true lengthComputable: false loaded: 0 returnValue: true
>
> srcElement: Object msCaching: "auto" onabort: null onerror: null
>   onload: null onloadend: null onloadstart: null onprogress: null
>   onreadystatechange: null ontimeout: null readyState: 4 response: ""
>   responseText: "" responseType: "text" responseURL: "" 0:
>
> target: Object msCaching: "auto" onabort: null onerror: null onload:
>   null onloadend: null onloadstart: null onprogress: null
>   onreadystatechange: null ontimeout: null readyState: 4 response: ""
>   responseText: "" responseType: "text" responseURL: "" 0:  timeStamp:
>   30184.21007896917 total: 0 type: "error"
>
> **proto**: Object
>
> headers: Object
>
> headers: Object size: 0
>
> **proto**: Object lazyUpdate: null
>
> normalizedNames: Object
>
> **proto**: Object message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error" name: "HttpErrorResponse" ok: false status: 0
>   statusText: "Unknown Error" url: null
>
> **proto**: Object

Do you have any idea about how to fix this issue?

Comment: this.httpClient.post("http://10.116.43.18:8002/user/login", request,  { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*'), observe: 'response' });

Comment: subscribe on component.ts file not here

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense anyway. Access-Control-Origin is a header that is supposed to be on the HTTP **response**, and be set by the **server** to allow CORS requests.